# and conquer algorithm - search for pattern in string

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to write a divide divide-and-conquer algorithm in pseudocode that finds how many occurrences of a 3-letter pattern there are in a given string of n letters.

Something like this in pseudocode:

*the pattern is fixed: XXY*

```
int searchString("CDSXXYZSE")  
    .  
    .  
    search for "XXY"  
    .  
    .  
return (1)
```

Or

```
int searchString("CDSXZXYZSE")  
    .  
    .  
    search for "XXY"  
    .  
    .  
return (0)
```

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the divide step i would split up your string parameter into all possible 3-letter combinations, in your example (CDS, DSX, XXY ...). Then test equality to the searched pattern and add up the number of matches in the conquer step.

Comment: What in case of AXXY or XXYA??

Comment: you break up your input string into all 3-length substrings, so AXXY would have AXX and XXY.